# get all records via operation and show in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, trailblazer

I have trouble with trailblazer when setting up a simple show all Things view.

**operation**

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  class ShowAll < Trailblazer::Operation
    include Model
    model Thing, :all   #why :all is not working here?

    def process
    end
  end
end
```

**controller**

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    run Word::ShowAll
  end
end
```

why is `:all` not working for getting all Things from the db but `:find` works to get one via its id?

Answer (score 1):

The best place to ask TRB questions is actually on Github channel.

I'm not sure where you found that example, as it is not supposed to work AFAIK, :find is a shortcut I believe, I've never actually used it.

All your logic should be defined inside the process method. http://trailblazer.to/gems/operation/1.1/api.html#process

Having said that, trying to get all records without some kind of pagination is a really bad idea, unless you are 100% sure that your table won't grow beyond several dozen records. Unless you know you don't have a large load. So to define that kind of shortcut is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Trailblazer::Model#model` as you're doing there is just a shortcut for overriding the `TrailBlazer::Operaration#model!` method. So what you seem to want to do is:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  class ShowAll < Trailblazer::Operation
    def model!(params)
      Thing.all # add any filtering or pagination here
    end
  end
end
```

And in your controller call `present` instead of `run` so that it sets up the model but doesn't call the `process` method of the operation.

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
    present Word::ShowAll
  end
end
```